# Bootstrap Column Content Centering and Absolute Positioning

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, cross-browser, css-position

I have a bootstrap row that has 3 columns. The columns display horizontally in everything except mobile. In mobile they stack vertically, which is what I want... here's the issue.

I have responsive (img-responsive) images within each of the 3 columns. In the mobile display, I want the images to be centered within the column. On top of that I need to have 2 div's with absolute positioning over the responsive images. It works fine in chrome, but in I.E. and FireFox, the images are not responsive due to the outer div which has display:inline-block.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="text-align:center;">
        <div style="margin-bottom:15px;position:relative;display: inline-block;">
            <div style="position:absolute;top:0;right:0;padding:5px;font-weight:bold;background-color:#bb091f;color:#FFF;">
                Live Deal
            </div>
            <img class="img-responsive" style="border:solid 1px #666;display:inline-block !important;" src="http://www.weekesisland.com/photos/atv.jpg" />
            <div class="deal2Timer" style="position:absolute;bottom:1px;right:1px;width:190px;opacity:.9;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="text-align:center;">
        <div style="margin-bottom:15px;position:relative;display: inline-block;">
            <div style="position:absolute;top:0;right:0;padding:5px;font-weight:bold;background-color:#bb091f;color:#FFF;">
                Live Deal
            </div>
            <img class="img-responsive" style="border:solid 1px #666;display:inline-block !important;" src="http://www.weekesisland.com/photos/atv.jpg" />
            <div class="deal3Timer" style="position:absolute;bottom:1px;right:1px;width:190px;opacity:.9;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="text-align:center;">
        <div style="margin-bottom:15px;position:relative;display: inline-block;">
            <div style="position:absolute;top:0;right:0;padding:5px;font-weight:bold;background-color:#bb091f;color:#FFF;">
                Live Deal
            </div>
            <img class="img-responsive" style="border:solid 1px #666;display:inline-block !important;" src="http://www.weekesisland.com/photos/atv.jpg" />
            <div class="deal4Timer" style="position:absolute;bottom:1px;right:1px;width:190px;opacity:.9;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's how it looks in chrome vs. firefox.

Chrome desktop:
[image]

Chrome mobile:
[image]

In mobile, when the windows width is smaller than the image, the image scales due to img-responsive.

Firefox desktop:
[image]

Firefox Mobile

[image]

Note how the firefox images are no longer responsive.... however it is centered in the column in the mobile display, and the absolute positioning of the 2 div's is correct.

Is there any way to accomplish this that is cross-browser compatible? I've tried a bunch of options, but without inline-block, I can't get the absolute elements positioned properly on the responsive image as well as centered in the column for the mobile display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did to fix it... it was simpler than I thought:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="text-align:center;">
    <div class="homeLiveDealMobile">
        <div class="liveDealBlock">
            Live Deal
        </div>
        <img class="img-responsive imgBorder" src="http://www.weekesisland.com/photos/atv.jpg" />
        <div class="deal3Timer homepageTimer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.liveDealBlock {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    padding:5px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#bb091f;
    color:#FFF;
}

.homeLiveDealMobile {
    margin-bottom:15px !important;
    position:relative;
}

.homepageTimer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:1px;
    right:1px;
    width:190px;
    opacity:.9;
}

@media(max-width:767px){
    .homeLiveDealMobile {
        max-width:391px !important;
        margin:auto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get better results as responsive images, I use jQuery.

You should try something like : [example jQuery reponsive image with **CODEPEN** link](http://responsivedesign.is/resources/images/jquery-picture)